# Javasctipt function running without being called?

Tags: javascript, button, console, blur

So I only have 6 lines of code in my page.js file and they are:

```
document.getElementById("desired").addEventListener("blur", gradeChange());
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", gradeChange());

function gradeChange() {                                                              
    var dog = document.getElementById("desired").value;                               
    console.log(dog);                                                                 
}
```

And in my page.html I have:

```
<input id="desired" type="text">
```

and somewhere else:

```
<button id="calculate" type="button">Calculate</button>
```

I thought it would work without the button, so that when I typed something in the textbox and then left the textbox, it would show up in the log. But nothing showed up, so I added the button to make it more straight forward. Still, it did nothing in the log. Any idea why nothing is showing up?

Comment: You are calling the function right there: `gradeChange()`. JavaScript evaluates arguments  first, so when you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`.

Comment: Is your code in your page before the HTML.  If so, move the `<script>` tag to AFTER the two items you're trying to call `.getElementById()` on.  The DOM elements must be loaded before you can run your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gradeChange() calls the function gradeChange

```
document.getElementById("desired").addEventListener("blur", gradeChange());
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", gradeChange());
```

Change gradeChange() to gradeChange

```
document.getElementById("desired").addEventListener("blur", gradeChange);
document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", gradeChange);
```

Comment: I changed this and it didn't solve the problem. I have the same problem, nothing shows up in log. Though I appreciate the correction. What could make this function fail to call?

Comment: try console.log('test'); Your dog variable could be null.

Comment: If this worked for you, would you please mark it as the answer? :)